# Tooltip Popup when mouseover disabled dates on Bootstrap 3 DateTimePicker v4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I've an array of disabled dates that is fetched using AJAX on page load. However, I would like to display a tooltip popup that shows "Promo Date" when the specified disabled dates are being moused over. Any ideas how can I do it?

```
$('#PickDate').datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    showTodayButton: true,
    minDate: parsedDate,
    defaultDate: startDate,
    format: 'DD MMM YYYY',
    disabledDates: dDatesArray,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All disabled dates are marked by the library with a `.disabled` class.

You can add a listner for [`dp.show`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpshow) and [`dp.update`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpupdate) and then you can selected disabled dates with jQuery (`$('td.day.disabled')`) and add title attribute (using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)) to get native tooltip.

If you want to use Bootstrap tooltip you can simply call [`.tooltip()`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-usage). Since the datetimepicker uses a HTML `<table>` you have to add `data-container="body"` to your element. As the [docs says](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-usage):

> When using tooltips on elements within a `.btn-group` or an `.input-group`, or on table-related elements (`<td>`, `<th>`, `<tr>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`), you'll have to specify the option `container: 'body'` to avoid unwanted side effects (such as the element growing wider and/or losing its rounded corners when the tooltip is triggered).

Here a working example:

```js
$('#PickDate').datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: false,
  showTodayButton: true,
  //minDate: parsedDate,
  //defaultDate: startDate,
  format: 'DD MMM YYYY',
  //disabledDates: dDatesArray,
  daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
}).on('dp.show dp.update', function(){
  $('td.day.disabled').each(function(index, element){
    var $element = $(element)
    $element.attr("title", "Promo Date");
    
    $element.data("container", "body");
    $element.tooltip()
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" id="PickDate">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```